# getting empty value of uncheck chekbox in vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs2, axios

guys, I m new to Vue can anybody suggest me what i m doing wrong 
here is code

```
<tr v-for="(item,index) in items">
  <td class="fancy">
     <input type="text" v-model="name[index]">
  </td>
  <td class="fancy">
     <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkview[index]" true-value="1" false-value="0" >
  </td>
  <td class="has-text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedit[index]" > 
   </td>
   <td class="has-text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkupdate[index]" >    
   </td>
  <td class="has-text-right">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkdelete[index]" > 
  </td>
</tr>
```

in script

```
   export default {
     data(){
        return{
                checkview:[],
                checkedit:[],
              checkupdate:[],
              checkdelete:[],
           }
         }
 methods: {
      submitTb(){
           console.log(this.checkview)
           console.log(this.checkedit)
           console.log(this.checkupdate)
           console.log(this.checkdelete)
           }
    }
```

suppose item lenght is 3 that mean 3 times checkview,checkedit,checkupdate and checkdelete is created illustration of frontend  as below

```
 items list | checkview  | checkedit   | checkupdate  | checkdelete
   --------------------------------------------------------------
    item1   | uncheckbox |  uncheckbox | uncheckbox | uncheckbox 
    item2   | uncheckbox |  uncheckbox | uncheckbox | uncheckbox 
    item3   | uncheckbox |  uncheckbox | uncheckbox | uncheckbox
```

now my problem is that when i does in console log in submitTb function i got nothing i.e no value expected value [0,0,0] but don't know why it got empty does any body tell me how i can assign initial value of check box as 0  i.e if user directly click on submit button then console.log should be like [0,0,0] what i m missing

Comment: `<input type="checkbox">` there is no trace of a checkbox in post data when its not ticked.

Comment: @Scuzzy i tried using false but it throws an error like Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in 0 can you help me with that I m too new for this type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello @rocky you can try something like this on axios success for where you are getting items  assign initial value like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

      self.checkview[i]=false
      self.checkedit[i]=false
      self.checkupdate[i]=false
      self.checkdelete[i]=false
 }
```